# Arduino ESP32 TwoWire "method" doesn't work

Tags: arduino, esp32

I have trouble using two sensors on two I2C interfaces.

The problem is, that I when I try to replace the `Wire.begin()` with something like this: `I2C.begin(21, 22)`, my sensor QMC5883L returns for x, y and z 0. I included the Wire library manually and created a TwoWire object:

```
#include <Wire.h>   
TwoWire I2C = TwoWire(0);
```

When I tried this, I commented the `_wire->begin()` in the library, It worked with the commented line **and** with `Wire.begin()` in the sketch, but when I try to replace `Wire.begin()` with `I2C.begin(21, 22)` it doesn't work anymore.

The reason, why this should work is that I want to create 2 interfaces like that and then give them to the `compass.begin(&I2C)` method. In the library I have this:

```
void QMC5883LCompass::init(TwoWire *theWire){
  _wire = theWire;
  _wire->begin(); // this is the line I commented, when getting the zeros...
  _writeReg(0x0B,0x01);
  setMode(0x01,0x0C,0x10,0X00); 
}
```

Did I forget something?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that when calling `_wire->begin()` is actually calling the default definition (from Wire.h):

```
bool begin(int sda=-1, int scl=-1, uint32_t frequency=0);
```

Default parameters -1 for SDA/SCL means default pins, wich overwrites the ones you added in the first `begin(...)`

Presuming you are using https://github.com/mprograms/QMC5883LCompass, the solution is to subclass QMC5883LCompass and override the `void QMC5883LCompass::init()` or create a new init(...) with your specific needs.

Comment: Okay, but the library had origanally only a `Wire.begin()` method (I rewrote this part, with `_wire->begin()` , because I thought that with `_wire = theWire`, _wire is not the default but the new TwoWire object. (I have that Idea from the BME280 library from GitHub). You do the same thing there, and I assume it works there (I don't have a BME280, but I saw an example).

Comment: Hm. Seems like I misunderstood what you changed and what was the original. What is working and what is not working? _wire.begin() works, but _wire.begin(21, 22) does not work? May the problem be that the library uses default Wire.xxx but you are initializing an separate object?

Comment: Okay, I know now, what was wrong (a stupid mistake). The default in the library was Wire.begin(), Wire.write(), Wire.read() etc. and I changed only Wire.begin() to _wire->begin(). I have done it now for all of this lines. Now it works : ) , but thx anyway, it was my fault, my question wasn't that clear... (Because I never thought that this could be my mistake xD)

Comment: Great that you found a solution!